# Get total of Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-6

How can I get a total of records after I used `skip` and `take` from a query?

Codes Working:

```
$records = Model::where('active', 1)
                 ->skip(($page -1 ) * $max)
                 ->take($max);
// List of records
$data = $records->get()

//Total of all records including the skip records
$total = $records->paginate()->total();
```

I want this way but Codes Not Working:

```
$records = Model::where('active', 1)
                 ->skip(($page -1 ) * $max)
                 ->take($max)->get();

//Not Working 
$total = $records->paginate()->total();

//Not Working 
$total = $records->total();

//Not Working wrong result
$total = $records->count();
```

How can I get the all total records in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `paginate()` method directly on your model:

```
$records = Model::where('active', 1)->paginate($recordsPerPage);
```

That will return a `LengthAwarePaginator` instance, which has a lot of useful methods:

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html

Such as `$records->total()`, `$records->perPage()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example your call paginate() is on the Query builder...
(Before you do ->get())

On your second example the paginate() call is on the collection, after your retrieved your results with ->get()

$records is a different thing in both , first is query builder, second is collection

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$records = Model::where('active', 1)
                 ->skip(($page -1 ) * $max)
                 ->take($max)->get();

$total = count($records);
```